# How to update a textview within a custom layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have created a custom layout which extends the viewgroup. My custom layouts contain a child which is a `relativelayout`. The `relativeLayout` then contain another 2 `TextViews` as its child. I am wondering if there is a way to update the `textviews` dynamically after the `onMeasure()` method and `onLayout()` is called? I have tried getting a reference to the `relativeLayout` in my `onMeasure()` and then change the `textView` that way but it wouldn't work because the textView changes didn't even get render. Also, I have tried getting the `TextView` using my `mainActivty` by inflating the `Relativelayout` and finding the textViews by id. However, this is not what I want because it changes the `measuredWidth()` of the original size of the `TextViews`.

I am stuck just stuck wondering if there is any other way I can call the textViews?

Comment: Create your own interface and implement to `textview`

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. Can you give me an example?